# What is a good introduction to root systems resp. root datum?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Is there one short reference, which does a good job in providing a dictionary between algebraic group over a field and its root systems/datum?

I have a basic background with algebraic geometry and algebra. I am familiar with Weyl groups, tori, Levi and Cartan decomposition,...  Nevertheless, I have a really hard time grasping the main observations involved in the “equivalence” of the categories.

Comment: Have you tried the articles (maybe by Tits?) near the beginning of the first of the Corvalis volumes?

Comment: No I have not, but I will have a look. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find what you want in Kleshchev 's [*Lectures on Algebraic Groups*](http://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~klesh/teaching/AGLN.pdf), a free online course.
It is 160 pages long, but you can probably skip the first 90 pages which are a general introduction to algebraic geometry.
Root systems are explained from  page 131 on.